# AsyncQueryHandler - IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

```
IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object:
```

I'm trying to query my product table using `AsyncQueryHandler`.

In the stacktrace `com.sdvd.www.sstore.CartActivity$1.onQueryComplete(CartActivity.java:134)` is pointing on this line but I am not sure how fix it:

```
if ((cursor != null) && cursor.moveToFirst())
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, productQuantity, productName FROM product WHERE productName= ?
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:123)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:236)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
      at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToFirst(CursorWrapper.java:71)
      at com.sdvd.www.sstore.CartActivity$1.onQueryComplete(CartActivity.java:134)
      at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my method where the error is occurring code:

```
    public void updateItem(boolean active, int position) {

        String[] projection = {
                ProductContract.ProductEntry._ID,
                ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
                ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME};


        TextView cartProductName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cart_product_name);



        QueryProductQtyAsyncQueryHandler addStockUsingBackgroundThread = new QueryProductQtyAsyncQueryHandler(this.getContentResolver()) {
            @Override
            protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
                super.onQueryComplete(token, cookie, cursor);

                Log.v("Inside onQueryComplete", cursor.toString() );
                //DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                if ((cursor != null) && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    // get the quantity?
                    int productQtyColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY);
                    currentStockQuantity = cursor.getString(productQtyColumnIndex);
                    cartProductQtyTxtView.setText(currentStockQuantity);
                    //return;
                }
            }
        };
        addStockUsingBackgroundThread.startQuery(1
                , null
                , ProductContract.ProductEntry.CONTENT_URI
                , projection
                , ProductContract.ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + "= ?"
                , new String[]{cartProductName.getText().toString()}
                , null);

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake I realised this is happening because I have overriden the onQueryComplete() method and I was calling cursor.close() inside that method. I removed the cursor.close() and it the error is gone.

Here is the class that contains the onQueryComplete():

```
public class QueryProductQtyAsyncQueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

    public QueryProductQtyAsyncQueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
        super(cr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
       // cursor.close(); //removed
    }
}
```